# Arranging subsites on several horizontal lines

Tags: page-layout, navigation, sub-site

I have an intranet for my company including more than 15 subsites.
They are all placed on the same line so I need to scroll right to see and click on the last ones.
Is there any way I can arrange them on 2 or 3 lines so it looks more ergonomic ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about navigation links i the top navigation bar.

You can place them as links in the quicklaunch to the left.

Have a look at this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca) that Microsoft has on just this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's nothing that's easily configurable through SharePoint options. If you're familiar with html and css, you can design the top nav however you'd like.

The simplest way is to add a custom css file that targets the respective elements in the top nav and alters the way they show up. There are plenty of resources around for doing this.

Another more advanced approach is to hide the top navigation control in the masterpage and build out a navigation menu from scratch. It can pull data in dynamically using SharePoint's REST api so new sites show up automatically as well.